# How to properly use jQuery.sap.log.debug instead of console.log in SAPUI5 v.1.38.39?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, console.log, sap-web-ide

### About environment:

- The used framework: **SAPUI5**
- version: **1.38.39**
- development environment: sap web-ide
- reproductible with OpenUI5 v.1.38

### About Issue :

Recommendation from UI5 : to **don't use console.log("message")**
Proposition from UI5: **use jQuery.sap.log.debug("message")** instead, documentation [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.39/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.html)
expected result : **see the "message"** in the console from chrome debugger"
actual result : **Don't see the "message"** in the console"

### Code part :

on my controller :

```js
onInit: function(){
  jQuery.sap.log.debug('onInit fired'); // display nothing in chrome console
  console.log('onInit fired'); // display "onInit fired" in chrome console
},
```

### Question:

Does someone has a **solution or idea** for solve this problem ?

### Remark:

1. My question is **probably simple**, but i **didn't find any solution
   nowhere**, and I am new to UI5, so I am asking here, thank you for your **help** and
   **comprehension**.
2. If someone also can tell me why this question (the only one I asked so far) lock me to ask further questions, I think the post respect [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) ? Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the log level to DEBUG?
If not try to add :

```
jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.Level.DEBUG)
```

Also, is there any particular reason you are using 1.38 and not something more recent?

Comment: thank you for your reply, no i just put jQuery.sap.log.debug(), may I ask where and how generally should I set the log level ? this version is used because it was build on this version and for compability with backend :)

Comment: This should work: 
    jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.Level.DEBUG)